# why I can doesn't link ssl lib(-lssl) into so's makefile?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

there is one so, the so contain one cpp. the cpp's includes:

```
include "openssl/evp.h"

OpenSSL_add_all_digests()
```

nm the so ,and see the symbol as U:

U OpenSSL_add_all_digests

thus I check the so' Makefile,it doesn't contain lib:libssl(-L -lssl) in makefile, but it can make so successfully.

but when I write one cpp to link the so and test it, If I doesn't link the libssl with test cpp, it will popup "undefined reference" error.

How to understand it?

Comment: The path `openssl/evp.h` probably exists relative to the location of the cpp file, so you don't have to declare it in the Makefile.

Comment: @Havenard   3ks, but I want know if add -L -l, not -I,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating so does NOT require all symbols to be resolved;
Generating executable requires all symbols to be resolved.

So if you generate a so, you can have "undefined reference", e.g.

testso.cpp:

```
void funcA();

void funcB()
{
  funcA();
}
```

And compile and link like below:

```
g++ -fPIC -o testso.o -c testso.cpp  # COmpile
g++ testso.o -shared -o libtestso.so  # Link
```

You can generate libtestso.so successfully.

But if you try to link it to an executable, you need to have funcA() defined.

Comment: but I use mingw using your command to creating the so, it popup undefined symbol,what's difference? ps: in linux, using g++, it is no problem

Comment: @jiafu Do you mean if you use g++ in mingw to compile the testso.cpp and JUST generate so, it will pop "undefined reference" error?

Comment: yes, so it confused me so that I asked this question.maybe the mingw can't provide same behavior with centos's gcc.